# Detect when AVPlayer reaches certain percentage played of the total duration?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

When a user is playing a video, I am trying to figure out when the user reaches a certain percentage played.

For example, the user playing a video and I want to show some view when the user reaches 50% played.

more clarification, is there a way to setup a "listener/observer" for when 50% occurs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best way to observe would probably be to use to `periodTimeObserver` from [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1385829-addperiodictimeobserver):

```
func addPeriodicTimeObserver() {
    // Invoke callback every half second
    let interval = CMTime(seconds: 0.5,
                          preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(NSEC_PER_SEC))
    // Queue on which to invoke the callback
    let mainQueue = DispatchQueue.main
    // Add time observer
    timeObserverToken =
        player.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: interval, queue: mainQueue) {
            [weak self] time in
            // Check whether the time has reached half of duration
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Just curious is there any benefit to using periodTimeObserver as opposed to doing what @rashwanL suggested in his answer?

Comment: @Changerrs Besides the usual advice of "you should use the official methods outlined in docs," I am not a video expert, but I could see how their internal implementation could be better because the "video time ticks" could be out-of-sync with the custom timer you created.